# set time start and end with php script

Tags: php, date, time

I'd like to range from 8 to 9 am and within 20 minutes with my views on the table
8,8:20,8:40:9
Now this is what I generally do so should Try  and display
Start and end time and the limited time of database calls

```
$nowtime = "15:45";
$endtime="17:45";
echo $nowtime;
$date =date("g:i",strtotime($nowtime . ' + 5 minute'),$endtime);
echo "<br>".$date;
```

then print one record   how can print start and end time

Comment: Your explanation is pretty unclear, and additionaly you should post your tries if you want someone to help you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
  <?php
    $start = microtime(true);

    //Your Script Content here

    $end = microtime(true);
    $time = number_format(($end - $start), 2);

    echo 'This page loaded in ', $time, ' seconds';
  ?>
```